# How to make the tabs appear in my JupyterLab Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-lab

I have been watching a Pytorch tutorial on youtube and there I saw that JupyterLab allows the user to have on the left panel an outline of the headlines that exist in the markdown cells of the Notebook (see picture below):

[image]

However the screen I see when I work with JupyterLab is the one below:

[image]

How can I have the headlines appear in my Notebook like in the first picture?

## ====================================

My initial attempt to run: jupyter `labextension install @jupyterlab/toc` failed because nodejs was not installed. When I installed nodejs via conda and run again `labextension install @jupyterlab/toc` I got again an error.  By looking at the log file I found that the most update version of nodejs installed by conda is not supported.

> > C:\Users\Alienware\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\npm.CMD pack @jupyterlab/toc npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v13.0.0 npm WARN npm You
> >     should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we npm WARN npm
> >     can't make any promises that npm will work with this version. npm WARN
> >     npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 6, 8, 9,
> >     10, 11, 12. npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at
> >     https://nodejs.org/ npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v13.0.0

What would be the best way to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like its `jupyterlab-toc` extension

## Installation

`jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/toc`

[Github repo](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-toc)

In case you have an error during installation with `conda`:

`conda install -c anaconda nodejs`

> ```
> npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v13.0.0
> npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
> npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
> npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12.
> npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
> ```

There is an issue on github: [npm does not support Node.js v13.0.0](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/30066)

One of the best things to do is just wait and ignore the warning:

One of the developers comment:

> The workaround is to ignore the warning. It is not an error and you
>   can still use npm until we release a fix.

You can also find info that it was fixed in v13.0.1
So you need just to wait untill anaconda nodejs is updated.

You should be able to install the extension now.

Comment: Thank you, can you see my updated post and possibly advise?

Comment: @user8270077 i've updated the answer. Check if it works for you.

Comment: Getting `An error occured. ValueError: "@jupyterlab/toc" is not a valid extension: No 'jupyterlab' key`. Launching this from Anaconda Powershell Prompt (Anaconda3), Windows 10.